# Getting error when trying to redirect WP site to mobile site

Tags: redirect, errors, mobile, server, configuration

I've tried a few different plugins to redirect a WP site to a static page for for mobile devices smaller than iPads. Of the several I've tried, I get the following error. Can someone tell me what's causing the error or direct me to a thread or article that I can follow to just create the code without a plugin? I'm trying to keep the plugin count as low as possible. Thanks!

*Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration.*

I'm using the latest version of WP 3.7.1.

core site: http://clients.weinsteinau.cgvcreative.com/
mobile: http://clients.m.weinsteinau.cgvcreative.com/

This is the error I get when I install the Equivelant Mobile Redirect plugin.

*Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /home/green83/public_html/clients/weinsteinau/wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php on line 77*

I don't have the exact code since I don't know where the error is coming from.

This is what happens when I activate the plugin:

*Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /home/green83/public_html/clients/weinsteinau/wp-includes/update.php on line 259*

Comment: Post your code please. Is that error _exactly_ what you see?

Comment: Also, that is before I even activate the plugin. That's what I get when I simply upload it.

Comment: Any idea why the plugin wants to connect to _wordpress.org_?

Comment: That's an excellent question. I had jetpack installed at one point but have since disabled and deleted it. That's the only thing I can think of that might want to connect with wordpress.org. I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I think it's just a generic warning. "Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration." leads me to think that it's something that would come up because someone *might* have a wordpress.org hosted site.

Comment: What would be your recommended way to redirect a WP site to a static mobile page? I don't know PHP. I can hack it if I find the right resource to walk me through it but that's about it.

Comment: wordpress.org doesn't host any sites. I wouldn't redirect to a mobile site. I like responsive, not dedicated mobile. You can redirect from any hook before headers are sent-- more or less before `wp_head`

Comment: I meant wordpress.com. I agree about using responsive instead. Couldn't talk the client into going that route this time. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Love to help more but this looks like it is either server related or much too broad. I can't tell.